# @Autowire using singleton vs prototype

Tags: spring, web, ejb, autowired

Take a look at the following code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{   
    @Autowired
    private FacadeRemote fr;

// code omitted   
}
```

|

```
@Component("user-details")
public class CustomUserServiceDetails implements UserDetailsService
{

    @Autowired
    private FacadeRemote fr;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        // omitted
    }

}
```

configuration:

```
<!-- JNDI Properties -->
    <util:properties id="jndiProps">
        <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.ejb.client.naming</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://127.0.0.1:4447</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="java.naming.client.ejb.context">true</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="boss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT">false</beans:prop>
    </util:properties>


    <!-- EJB look up -->
    <jee:remote-slsb id="ns" jndi-name="Layer//myejb!com.uni.ag.FacadeRemote"
        environment-ref="jndiProps" resource-ref="false"
        business-interface="com.uni.ag.FacadeRemote"
        lookup-home-on-startup="true">
    </jee:remote-slsb>
```

In the following example how does @Autowire works:
Are the two classes using the same instance of FacadeRemote ?
In general how can I learn @Autowire behaviour in relation to thread-safety ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost no relation between `@Autowired` and thread-safety. The only responsibility of Spring IoC is to inject declared dependencies, taking into account their scope etc. It's your responsibility to make sure, that all beans will work correctly in multi-threaded applications. It means for example that for singleton beans all state that this bean holds should be synchronized.

Regarding your first question: there will be injected a proxy to `FacadeRemote` (to allow for example transations of checked exception `RemoteException` to an unchecked exception). According to the Spring Spec inside this proxy will be a cached instance of remote interface to `FacadeRemote`.

Comment: so by default the two instance variables belonging to the two different classes will refer to the same object (singleto policy). If I want them to refer to two distinct object I would have to specify prototype policy ?

Comment: I dont't think that Spring will allow you to set `prototype` policy to this kind of beans. Please bear in mind that remote EJBs are just a business delegates. (see: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#ejb-introduction). Here (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) you can find all informations about Spring scopes.